# Using xmltodict for Python, how can I reference a non-specific XML property and change the value?

Tags: python, xml, xmltodict

I have an xml file as such:

```
<root processName="someName" >
    <Property name="FirstProp" value="one" />
    <Property name="SecondProp" value="two" />
    <Property name="ThirdProp" value="three" />
</root>
```

Is it possible, using xmltodict, to find the Property "SecondProp" without knowing the specific index and change value from "two" to "seventeen"? (below)

Code:

```
import os
import xmltodict

text_file = open("testxml.xml", "r")
tst = text_file.read()

obj = xmltodict.parse(tst)

print(obj['root']['@processName'])
print(obj['root']['Property'][0])
print(obj['root']['Property'][1])
print(obj['root']['Property'][2])
```

Output:

```
someName
OrderedDict([('@name', 'FirstProp'), ('@value', 'one')])
OrderedDict([('@name', 'SecondProp'), ('@value', 'two')])
OrderedDict([('@name', 'ThirdProp'), ('@value', 'three')])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate through `obj['root']['Property']` and find the one you're looking for. The way XML is parsed with xmltodict, makes `obj['root']['Property']` a list and not a dict.

Example:

```
for x in obj['root']['Property']:
    if x['@name'] == 'SecondProp':
        # do whatever you want
```